# Is this process stationary?

Tags: time-series, autoregressive

Consider this process: $$y_t = \rho y_{t-1} + u_t$$ where $|\rho|<1$ and $u_t$ is stationary. Question: is $y_t$ then stationary? I believe that this is not true but I could not find a counter example.

In a previous question ([$|\rho|<1 \iff $ AR(1) Process stationary](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/285410/rho1-iff-ar1-process-stationary)) I could already show that $y_t$ is not necessarily an AR(1) process (yet still a stationary process).

Comment: Hint: when you perform the same deterministic arithmetic operation at every place in a stationary process, you must still have a stationary process.  What do you get when you start with $(u_t)$ and, for each $t$, construct $u_t + \rho u_{t-1} + \rho^2 u_{t-2} + \cdots + \rho^n u_{t-n} + \cdots$?

Comment: I am not sure wether I got your hint... I know that plugging in recursively yields $y_t = \sum_{i=0}^\infty\rho^{i}u_{t-i}$ (this limit exists as $|\rho|<1$). But how does this help me?

Comment: You just proved $(y_t)$ is stationary if $(u_t)$ is.

Comment: But why? To what theorem do you refer?

(I know that this is true if $(u_t)$ is white noise but here we only have stationarity).

Comment: I am referring to the very first sentence of my very first comment.  I was hoping you would already know this or be able to demonstrate it: it seems to follow immediately from the definition of "stationary," although a subtler argument is needed to extend it from a finite process to the limit implied by the infinite sum.